# Why wont NetBeans find my main class?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been trying to get net beans to find my main class which I'm thinking is the part where I have it output all 3 areas. According to the school I've correctly coded it but net beans and eclipse refuse to run it if anyone can point out my error and show me how to fix it I'd love it thanks.

```
package shape
public class Shape {

    class circle {

        int r;
        int r1;
        double pi;

        double FindArea(int a, int b, double c) {
            r = a;
            r1 = b;
            pi = c;
            return r * r1 * pi;
        }

        class rectangle {

            int height;
            int width;

            int RFindArea(int d, int e) {
                height = d;
                width = e;
                return width * height;
            }
        }

        class square {

            int s;

            int SFindArea(int f) {
                s = f;
                return s ^ 2;
            }
        }

        class result {

            public void main(String[] args) {
                circle objCircle = new circle();
                System.out.println(objCircle.FindArea(10, 10, 3.14));
                rectangle objRec = new rectangle();
                System.out.println(objRec.RFindArea(20, 15));
                square objS = new square();
                System.out.println(objS.SFindArea(5));

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is not `public static void main` method...and your have an extra `}` at the end, no idea where that's coming from...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I forgot to put it in the question but it suposed to be at the end where the result class is the extra } is coming from NetBeans it for some reason requires me to put a pages worth of them on each project

Comment: You have inner class within inner class within inner class, it's all a bit crazy. Consider using a separate file for each class...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have tried that but its been giving me issues like it wont find the other classes from separate files this is also how the schools example looks so either they're teaching wrong or I'm wrong

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually never mind I must've done something wrong when I was making separate class files I followed exactly what you said and it worked perfectly thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your main method should be `static`

```
public static void main(String[] ar)
```

When JVM invokes main class it doesn't create instance of the class, it just loads the class and invokes `static` `main()` method

Comment: And since it's an inner class, will need to be declared `static`, along with `circle`...which just a mess...

Comment: @Jigar Joshi when I add the static bit onto it net beans says "illegal static decleration in inner class Shape.circle.result modifier static is only allowed in constant variable declerations"