# Averaging grades using objects in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to average 6 grades for two different people for school, I have all the grades for each student in different classes I was wondering

How can I import the numbers that I enter for each students object that I create?

```
//first class
public class GradesA {
int art;
int math;
int science;

int AddGrades(int a, int b, int c){
    art = a;
    math = b;
    science = c;
    return a+b+c;

}}
//second class
public class GradesB {
 int english;
 int carpentry;
 int geography;

int AddGradesB(int a,int b,int c){
    english = a;
    carpentry = b;
    geography = c;
    return a+b+c;

}}

//final class
public class Classes {
  public static void main(String[]args){
      GradesA objGrades = new GradesA();
      System.out.println(objGrades.AddGrades(100,85,95));
      GradesB objGradesB = new GradesB();
      System.out.println (objGradesB.AddGradesB(95,85,75));           
    }}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski will it be able to pull the grades from the final class? If so then that would be what I need.

Comment: Why do you have the grades in different classes? What is that supposed to accomplish? Why not have them all in one class and have a Grades object where you can get and set grades?

Comment: Also, to avoid confusion, you should use camelcase for your methods.

Comment: @jordaniac89 the school requires me to put them in different classes

Comment: @MrGamma195 did my answer help u?

Comment: @KickButtowski it was helpful yes, but I dont fully understand how to use this method I've not be taught how to do this yet they would like something similar to another program I wrote 
i know this code is wrong but it needs to be something similar to this I'll know how to fix it based on this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644550/why-wont-netbeans-find-my-main-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood what you are looking for

**Since**

```
int addGrades(int a, int b, int c){
```

return and integer

why do not you just divide return number from this function by 3 and get your average that you are looking for.

If you want to have access to data fields `art`, `math`, and `science` values

you need **getters** and **setters** like follwing example for `art` data filed

**setter** function is

```
public void setArt(int art){
   this.art = art;
}
```

**getter** function is

```
public int getArt(){
   return this.art;
}
```

[Read More About Setter and Getter](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getter-setter-use-or-not-use)